# app only requesting location acces when in use

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use requestAlwaysAuthorization but for some reason it only gives the options to allow once, allow when in use, or dont allow. This is my code.

```
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            @unknown default:
            break
        }
        } else {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.  When you request "Always" permission the user is prompted for "When In Use" and your app receives "Provisional always" permission.  After some time of your app actually using location in the background and the user actually using your app they are prompted to upgrade to "Always".  You can speed things up in iOS 14.3 and later by asking for when in use and then asking for always once you have when in use permission

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation for [`requestAlwaysAuthorization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization):

> You must call this or the requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method before your app can receive location information. **To call this method, you must have both NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in your app’s Info.plist file**. You may call requestAlwaysAuthorization() when the current authorization state is either:
>
> Not Determined — CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
>
> When In Use — CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse
>
> Use the locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method on the CLLocationManager delegate to receive updates when the user makes permission choices.
>
> Core Location limits calls to requestAlwaysAuthorization(). **After your app calls this method, further calls have no effect**.

Based on this, few things could be wrong with your code.

1. Too many calls to `requestAlwaysAuthorization`. This should be sufficient:

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
     switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
     case .notDetermined, .authorizedWhenInUse:
             locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
     default:
        print("Cannot ask user for requestAlwaysAuthorization")
     }
}
```

When user has already denied location permission, asking for it again will not show the popup.

2. Missing `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `Info.plist`. Define non-empty strings for these in your Info.plist.
3. Finally try reinstalling the app on device/simulator to clear previously granted or denied location permissions

Comment: Im aware of all those but im afraid the issue is on apples end. Many other people have tried requesting always authorization but instead, first it requests in use, then later in the apps life cycle it asks to change to always authorization.